# Mertens' asymptotic formula for $\prod \left(1-p^{-1}\right)$ without constant

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I've heard that there is an easy way to derive the asymptotic
$$\prod_{p\le x} \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \sim \frac{c}{\log(x)}$$
if one isn't interested in deriving $c=e^{-\gamma}$. I don't see how to do this, however.
Does anyone here know where I could find a simple proof of this statement or even write down a proof for me?

I'm quite new to number theory, so if you only assumed minimal background, that would be very helpful. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Perhaps that this [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105714/showing-that-log-logn1-leq-1-sum-limits-p-leq-n-frac1p/105728#105728) will help.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See pages 21-22 of Gérald Tenenbaum and Michel Mendès France, The Prime Numbers and Their Distribution. I found that by typing $$\rm Mertens\ formula$$ into the web. Many other possibly useful references came up, as well; for example, the discussion starting on page 88 of [Hildebrand's notes](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/ant/main3.pdf).

Comment: Cheers! ${}{}{}{}$